When saving and loading Keras or TensorFlow models: How do I disable/hide the warnings that appear when using the .h5 extension?
I am trying to save and load Keras and/or TensorFlow models, and approaching the problem by following the Keras documentation and a TensorFlow tutorial.  In VS Code on my PC, both the native .keras format and the SavedModel format described in the TensorFlow tutorial return errors.  However, the following near-minimal example using the legacy .h5 format does complete without errors (this example is adapted from the Keras documentation).
import keras

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=(3,)),
        keras.layers.Softmax(),
    ],
)
model.save('model.h5')
loaded_model = keras.saving.load_model('model.h5')

And yet it also displays two warnings, which become annoying when running the model many times:
WARNING:absl:You are saving your model as an HDF5 file via model.save() or keras.saving.save_model(model). This file format is considered legacy. We recommend using instead the native Keras format, e.g. model.save('my_model.keras') or keras.saving.save_model(model, 'my_model.keras').
WARNING:absl:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was not compiled. Compile it manually.
The first corresponds to the .save method and the second to the .load_model method.
How can these warnings be suppressed so that they do not appear on every run?

For reference, I have tried adding the following without success.
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.config.disable_interactive_logging()


Not to sound like an A-hole; but, there's a reason for the warning. Why not just save it the newer way?
To answer your question you can use: python your_script.py 2>/dev/null

Just be aware that will direct all stderr to a blackhole.
